# How do I Access Shared Files on a Samba Domain Controller from Win 7?

Tags: permissions, file-sharing, samba4

I set up a Ubuntu 14.04 Server as a domain controller.  A Windows 7 client can join the domain, show the Samba shared directories in the network but cannot open any of them except the user's home directory.  The message says I do not have permission to access the directory.  I have searched "AskUbuntu" and searched the web via Google and have not found a solution.

My Smb.conf file is:

```
# Global parameters
[global]
    netbios name = FRANK-N-STEIN
    workgroup = TUX-NET
##  passdb backend = tbdsam
#   os level = 33
    wins support = yes
    preferred master = yes
#   local master = yes
#   domain master = yes
    security = domain
    domain logons = yes
#   logon path = \\%N\profiles\%u
# *************************************************
    passwd chat = *New*Password* %n\n *Re-enter*new*password* %n\n *Password*changed*
    username map = /etc/samba/smbusers
    syslog = 0
    name resolve order = wins bcast hosts
    printcap name = CUPS
    show add printer wizard = No
    add user script = /usr/sbin/useradd -m %u
    delete user script = /usr/sbin/userdel -r %u
    add group script = /usr/sbin/groupadd %g
    delete group script = /usr/sbin/groupdel %g
    add user to group script = /usr/sbin/usermod -G %g %u
    add machine script = /usr/sbin/useradd -s /bin/false -d /dev/null %u
    logon script = scripts\logon.bat
#   logon path =
    logon drive = H:
    printing = cups
# *******************************************************

[homes]
    comment = Home Directories
    valid users = %S
    read only = No
    browseable = No


[netlogon]
    comment = Network Logon Service
    path = /var/lib/samba/netlogon
    guest ok = Yes

[accounts]
    comment = Accounting Files
    path = /media/ken/Linux-Data/data/accounts
    writable = yes
    read only = No
    guest ok = yes
    valid users = @ntadmin
    browseable = yes 
    create mode = 0660
    directory mode = 0770
    public = yes

[finsvcs]
    comment = Financial Services Files
    path = /media/ken/Linux-Data/data/finsvcs
    writeable = yes
    read only = No
    guest ok = yes
    valid users = @ntadmin
    browseable = yes
    create mode = 0660
    directory mode = 0770
    public = yes

[printers]
    comment = SMB Print Spool
    path = /var/spool/samba
    guest ok = Yes
    printable = Yes
    use client driver = Yes
    default devmode = Yes
    browseable = No
```

I am trying to duplicate the configuration in the "Samba 3 by Example" book for the small office in Chapter 3.

For the "valid users" line in the shares section, I have tried all combinations of group names (@{group name} and individual users.  I have also tried many variations of "chown" and "chmod" to change permissions of the share directories.

Here are permissions for the parent directory of the shared files:

```
drwsrwsr-x  6 ken  ntadmin  4096 May 16 11:45 data
```

Here are permissions for the two share directories:

```
drwxrwsr-x 2 ken accounts 4096 May 16 11:38 accounts
drwxrwsr-x 2 ken finsrvcs 4096 May 16 11:39 finsvcs
```

I just noticed the different spelling of the group and directory in th second line.  I will track down and correct that error.

I hope someone has an answer.  I have spent hours trying to access the folders from Win 7.

Thanks, in advance.